# Set a listener for a button within a ListView (without having the getView method ?)

Tags: android, listview, button, listener

I have in my application a Listview displaying content from a database. This is a custom clickable listview, and I want to add a button for every element of the listview, so when you click on this button, it will give a phone call and dial a specific number.

I have read a few similar topics but all refer to a "getView" method in the adapter, but I have no idea what it refers to. Here is my relevant code about for my listview:

```
private void displayListView() {

    // getExtra
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("title", "Choose here :");
    String inInterval = bundle.getString("inInterval");
    Log.d(TAG, "inInterval = " + inInterval);

    poititle.setText(title);


    // put the results of the method in a cursor
    Cursor c = dbHelper.findPoiInTable(inInterval);

    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_STREET, DatabaseAdapter.COL_WEBSITE,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_TELEPHONE, DatabaseAdapter.COL_REMARKS,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_PRICE };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.street, R.id.website,
            R.id.telephone, R.id.remarks, R.id.price };

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poilistview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        // Comportement des éléments de la listview
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    POIActivity.class);

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String website = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website))
                    .getText().toString();
            String telephone = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.telephone)).getText().toString();
            String remarks = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remarks))
                    .getText().toString();
            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price))
                    .getText().toString();
            // i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, name) ;
            i.putExtra(ID_NAME, name);
            i.putExtra(ID_WEBSITE, website);
            i.putExtra(ID_TELEPHONE, telephone);
            i.putExtra(ID_REMARKS, remarks);
            i.putExtra(ID_PRICE, price);
            startActivity(i);


        }

    }); }
```

And here is my button definition in the XML file :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/callButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowImage"
    android:text=" Call "
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

I have of course tried the usual way of setting listener (.setOnClickListener etc.) but I guess something must really be done from my displayListView() method.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Setting the click for a button without using the `getView` method is impossible.
You need to understand how to work with Adapters.
Every adapter have a method called `getView` that gets position as a parameter and the Adapter returns the view that need to be in this position.
You need to override the `SimpleCursorAdapter` and its `getView` method, and when creating your view (`R.layout.poi_info`), you need to assign your click listener to the button.
What you did now is when clicking an item from the list (not the button) you listener is fired.
Anyway, this is a subject with a lot of discussions and a quick search in Google can give you the answer.
Here's a tutorial I've found:
http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Good luck

Edit - Example:

Please notice that I used `newView` here. After you will read more about adapters read about CursorAdapter and you will understand what is it. This Adapter have a little different behavior.

```
public class ExtendedSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public ExtendedSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        }

        public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
            View v = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
            v.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, I am gonna study more about adapters then. Just a question though : so far, my code is working perfectly, I can do everything I want with my list (except for the button listener), every element is clickable and behave the right way. Is making the changes you suggested gonna require to rewrite it all, add new classes ? I already use a SimpleCursorAdaptater, is it possible to integrate the getView method directly in my code or the whole logic is to rethink ? Thanks =)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it was a CursorAdapter, I thought it was a ArrayAdapter, but the difference is not big. To your question, no, the new adapter doesn't change any of your logic. Think of an adapter as something the connects between the UI and the data you want to present (in your case, data from a DB). Adapters take the data and create the items that will be in your list. Android supplies basic adapters, and what you need to do is extend theme to your use. I added an example of what can be your change in the adapter in the answer.